# Is there an equivalent in LINQ for the SQL Server PARTITION OVER functionality?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there an equivalent in LINQ for the SQL Server PARTITION OVER functionality?

```
SELECT Decision_ID ,
       ID
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Decision_ID 
                           ORDER BY Decision_ID, ID ASC ) calcAmend
FROM   dbo.Decision_Data
```

which gives the ranking of each record

Answer (score 2):

```
DecisionData
    .GroupBy(d => d.DecisionID,
        (key, dd) => dd
                     .OrderBy(d => d.Id)
                     .Select((d, i) => new {d.DecisionId, d.Id, calcAmend = i}))
    .SelectMany(d => d)
```

Comment: Why is what? Please expand.

Comment: i just dont get it... i want someone explain it for me :(